# Manjaro Linux with LispWorks

Tags: manjaro, lisp

Can anyone of you help me with this error:

```
LispWorks(R): The Common Lisp Programming Environment Personal Edition Copyright (C) 1987-2012 LispWorks Ltd.  All rights reserved. Version
6.1.1 Saved by LispWorks as lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux, at 06 Dec 2012 16:51 User vlad on vlad Error during GUI startup:   Could not register handle for external module "-lgtk-x11-2.0":  /lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64.

DESCRIPTION: Output Backtrace <and a simple test case, if possible>

IMPACT: Broken/Annoying/Data Loss/Missing Error/New Feature/Performance Loss

URGENCY: ASAP/Current Release/Next Release/Future Release/None



PRODUCT CONFIGURATION:

  LispWorks Personal Edition 6.1.1

Process name: /usr/local/lib/LispWorksPersonal/./lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux  ID: 5445    Started at: 2016/11/04 1:37:13

Save history:

1: lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-base Saved by davef as lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-base, at 03 Nov 2011 13:25

2: lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken Saved by davef as lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken, at 03 Nov 2011 14:00

3: lispworks-6-1-1-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken Saved by davef as lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux, at 06 Dec 2012 16:51 LispWorks
6.1.1 - Personal Edition

Loaded Modules: 

Public patches:  Private patches:  CAPI-GTK-DESTROY-REPRESENTATION

Foreign modules:   #<FLI::INTERNAL-MODULE :LISP : exports = 0>  
#<FLI::INTERNAL-MODULE :CALLBACKS : exports = 0>   #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgthread-2.0"  {/usr/lib32/libgthread-2.0.so.0}: handle = #x097DD860; exports = 0>  
#<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>

Signal Handlers 2       SYSTEM::SIGINT-HANDLER 13      SYSTEM::THE-NULL-FUNCTION 17      SYSTEM::GET-CHILDREN-INF

HOST CONFIGURATION:

  vlad (x86_64), Linux 4.4.28-2-MANJARO   Manjaro Linux \r  (\n) (\l)

LWSerialNumber: Unknown

Site: Unknown

GTK+ not loaded

Backtrace:
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 1/16 internal, 0/4 external>



Call to (SUBFUNCTION 1 ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT) {offset 186}   SYSTEM::C : #<SIMPLE-ERROR 200D3B5B>

Binding frame:   CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : T

Handler frame: NIL Call to SIGNAL {offset 1446}   CONDITIONS::DATUM    : #<SIMPLE-ERROR 200D3B5B>   CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : NIL

Binding frame:   CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : NIL

Catch frame: CONDITIONS::SIGNAL-CATCH

Binding frame:   CONDITIONS::*BROKEN-ON-SIGNALS* : NIL

Call to CONDITIONS::CONDITIONS-ERROR {offset 430}   CONDITIONS::DATUM  : "Could not register handle for external module ~S:~% ~A."   CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : ("-lgtk-x11-2.0" "/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64")

Call to ERROR {offset 67}   SYSTEM::ESTRING : "Could not register handle for external module ~S:~% ~A."   SYSTEM::EARGS   : ("-lgtk-x11-2.0" "/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64")

Binding frame:   FLI::*DLOPEN-FLAGS* : T

Call to FLI::CONNECT-TO-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 319}   FLI::MODULE :
#<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>   TYPE        : :MANUAL   FLI::ERRORP : T

Call to FLI::CREATE-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 275}   FLI::NAME           : "-lgtk-x11-2.0"   FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE   FLI::FILENAME : NIL   FLI::MODULE           : #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0" : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>   OPEN                  : T   FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION   FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT   FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to FLI:REGISTER-MODULE {offset 146}   FLI::NAME             : "-lgtk-x11-2.0"   FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE   FLI::LIFETIME   : :SESSION   FLI::REAL-NAME        : NIL   FLI::FILE-NAME        : NIL FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT   FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to LWGTK:INITIALIZE-GTK-LIBRARY {offset 999}

Call to CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::ENSURE-GTK-INITIALIZED {offset 21}

Call to (METHOD CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START ((EQL :GTK))) {offset 11}   CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::LOOK-AND-FEEL : :DONT-KNOW

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 311}   CLOS::ARGS            : (:GTK)   CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #<CLOS::CACHE-INFO CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START [8/2] >   CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}     : #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START 217FEBA2>

Call to CAPI-INTERNALS:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 60}   CAPI::ARGS      : (:START-FUNCTIONS ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER))) :ENVIRONMENT :CAPI)   CAPI::ENVIRONMENT     : :CAPI   PACKAGE          : NIL   CAPI::LIBRARY         : NIL   CAPI::START-FUNCTIONS : ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER)))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::START-CAPI-ENVIRONMENT {offset 24}   LISPWORKS-TOOLS::ARGS : NIL

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 311}   CLOS::ARGS            : (#<ENVIRONMENT::CAPI-ENVIRONMENT 21BCCF4B> NIL)   CLOS::.CACHE-INFO. {Closed} : #<CLOS::CACHE-INFO ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START [8/2] >   CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START 20979E5A>

Handler frame: ((ERROR . #<Function 1 subfunction of ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT 21E1A0EA>)) Call to ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 158}   SYSTEM::ARGS          : NIL   SYSTEM::OLD  {Closed} : #<Function ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT 20979E92>

Binding frame:   MP:*INITIAL-PROCESSES* : (("The idle process" (:PRIORITY -536870912 :RESTART-ACTION :CONTINUE :INTERNAL-SERVER :IDLE) MP::PROCESS-IDLE-FUNCTION))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::I-RESTART-WITH-ENVIRONMENT-AUX {offset 210}   ENVIRONMENT::TTY-LISTENER-P : NIL

Call to SYSTEM::RESTART-HOOK {offset 96}   FUNCTION : SYSTEM::%TOP-LEVEL

Restart frame: (SYSTEM::TOP-LEVEL) Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . RESTART-CASE)

Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . 1)

Catch frame: SYSTEM::EXIT-LISPWORKS

Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE {offset 421}

Catch frame: SYSTEM::START-UP

Catch frame: SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION

Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 57}

Call to SYSTEM::CALL-IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 12}

Catch frame: (NIL)

Call to SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION {offset 50}   SYSTEM::GC-MESSAGES : :DONT-KNOW


SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION

 Generation 0:  Total Size 515K, Allocated 377K, Free 130K 
          Segment 20090128: Total Size 507K, Allocated 377K, Free 126K
                    minimum free space 64K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 21EDE100: Total Size 7K, Allocated 0K, Free 3K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =2  Generation 1:  Total Size 308K, Allocated 110K, Free 189K 
          Segment 2070F0C0: Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K
                    minimum free space 3K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =4
          Segment 200540A8: Total Size 240K, Allocated 110K, Free 125K
                    minimum free space 0K, static  Generation 2:  Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K 
          Segment 20F1C640: Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K
                    minimum free space 117K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =4  Generation 3:  Total Size 30387K, Allocated 30247K, Free 128K 
          Segment 2010F0C0: Total Size 6144K, Allocated 6139K, Free 0K
                    minimum free space 3K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 20F2D6B8: Total Size 16066K, Allocated 15934K, Free 128K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 20720138: Total Size 8177K, Allocated 8173K, Free 0K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10

Total Size 31616K, Allocated 30735K, Free 511K
```

I've try to install some libraries, to reinstall the program, and some other things but for nothing... Whatever I've try it's the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Lispworks is old and not 64bit compilant, so it needs i386 version of gtk2 libraries

I solved it by installing this:

```
sudo pacman -S gtk2
```

Although I don't know if this is useful to you because the log of my problem was as follows:

```
LispWorks(R): The Common Lisp Programming Environment Personal Edition
Copyright (C) 1987-2019 LispWorks Ltd.  All rights reserved.
Version 7.1.2
Saved by LispWorks as lispworks-personal-7-1-2-amd64-linux, at 29 Nov 2019 18:00
User drago on drago-hp
Error during GUI startup:
  Could not register handle for external module "-lgtk-x11-2.0" (no file-name):
 -lgtk-x11-2.0.

DESCRIPTION: Output Backtrace <and a simple test case, if possible>

IMPACT: Broken/Annoying/Data Loss/Missing Error/New Feature/Performance Loss

URGENCY: ASAP/Current Release/Next Release/Future Release/None



PRODUCT CONFIGURATION:

  LispWorks Personal Edition 7.1.2

Process name: /usr/local/lib64/LispWorksPersonal/lispworks-personal-7-1-2-amd64-linux
   ID: 27171    Started at: 2022/02/01 16:00:52

Save history:

1: lispworks-7-1-0-0-amd64-linux-release-base
Saved by martin as lispworks-7-1-0-0-amd64-linux-release-base, at 17 May 2017 19:00

2: lispworks-7-1-0-0-amd64-linux-release-gtk-shaken
Saved by martin as lispworks-7-1-0-0-amd64-linux-release-gtk-shaken, at 17 May 2017 19:32

3: lispworks-7-1-2-0-amd64-linux-release-gtk-shaken
Saved by martin as lispworks-personal-7-1-2-amd64-linux, at 29 Nov 2019 18:00
LispWorks 7.1.2 - Personal Edition

Loaded Modules: 

Public patches: 

Foreign modules:
  #<FLI::INTERNAL-MODULE :LISP : exports = 0>
  #<FLI::INTERNAL-MODULE :CALLBACKS : exports = 0>
  #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgthread-2.0"  {/usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0}: handle = #x015091E0; exports = 0>
  #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>

Signal Handlers
2       SYSTEM::SIGINT-HANDLER
13      SYSTEM::THE-NULL-FUNCTION
17      SYSTEM::GET-CHILDREN-INF

Added features: (:LISPWORKS-PERSONAL-EDITION)

HOST CONFIGURATION:

  drago-hp (x86_64), Linux 5.15.16-1-MANJARO
  Manjaro Linux \r  (\n) (\l)

LWSerialNumber: Unknown

Site: Unknown

GTK+ not loaded

Backtrace:
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 3/16 internal, 0/4 external>



Call to (SUBFUNCTION 1 ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT) {offset 233}
  SYSTEM::C : #<SIMPLE-ERROR 40200BEC5B>

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : T

Handler frame: NIL
Call to SIGNAL {offset 1083}
  CONDITIONS::DATUM     : #<SIMPLE-ERROR 40200BEC5B>
  CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : NIL

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : NIL

Catch frame: CONDITIONS::SIGNAL-CATCH

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*BROKEN-ON-SIGNALS* : NIL

Call to CONDITIONS::CONDITIONS-ERROR {offset 516}
  CONDITIONS::DATUM     : "~@[When trying to find the address of ~a: ~]Could not register handle for external module ~S ~:[(no file-name)~;(file-name ~a)~]:~% ~A."
  CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : (NIL #1="-lgtk-x11-2.0" NIL #1# "libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Call to ERROR {offset 123}
  SYSTEM::ESTRING : "~@[When trying to find the address of ~a: ~]Could not register handle for external module ~S ~:[(no file-name)~;(file-name ~a)~]:~% ~A."
  SYSTEM::EARGS   : (NIL #1="-lgtk-x11-2.0" NIL #1# "libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Binding frame:
  FLI::*DLOPEN-FLAGS* : T

Call to FLI::CONNECT-TO-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 402}
  FLI::MODULE : #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>
  TYPE        : :MANUAL
  FLI::ERRORP : T

Call to FLI::CREATE-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 365}
  FLI::NAME             : "-lgtk-x11-2.0"
  FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE
  FLI::FILENAME         : NIL
  FLI::MODULE           : #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>
  DBG::|rest-|          : (:LIFETIME :SESSION :ADD-LIB-PATH NIL :DLOPEN-FLAGS FLI::DEFAULT)
  OPEN                  : T
  FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION
  FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT
  FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to FLI:REGISTER-MODULE {offset 500}
  FLI::NAME             : "-lgtk-x11-2.0"
  DBG::|rest-|          : (:CONNECTION-STYLE :IMMEDIATE :LIFETIME :SESSION)
  FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE
  FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION
  FLI::REAL-NAME        : NIL
  FLI::FILE-NAME        : NIL
  FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT
  FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to LWGTK:INITIALIZE-GTK-LIBRARY {offset 108}

Call to CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::ENSURE-GTK-INITIALIZED {offset 32}

Call to (METHOD CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START ((EQL :GTK))) {offset 21}
  CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::LOOK-AND-FEEL : :DONT-KNOW

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 452}
  CLOS::ARGS                   : (:GTK)
  CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #<CLOS::CACHE-INFO CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START [8/2] >
  CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START 41307E7624>

Call to CAPI-INTERNALS:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 196}
  DBG::|rest-|          : (:START-FUNCTIONS ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER))) :ENVIRONMENT :CAPI)
  CAPI::ENVIRONMENT     : :CAPI
  PACKAGE               : NIL
  CAPI::LIBRARY         : NIL
  CAPI::START-FUNCTIONS : ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER)))

Call to LISPWORKS-TOOLS:START-LISPWORKS {offset 233}
  DBG::|rest-|           : NIL
  LISPWORKS-TOOLS::TOOLS : (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER)

Call to ENVIRONMENT::START-CAPI-ENVIRONMENT {offset 163}
  LISPWORKS-TOOLS::ARGS : NIL

Call to (METHOD ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START (ENVIRONMENT::CAPI-ENVIRONMENT)) {offset 164}
  ENVIRONMENT::ENV  : :DONT-KNOW
  ENVIRONMENT::ARGS : NIL

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 452}
  CLOS::ARGS                   : (#<ENVIRONMENT::CAPI-ENVIRONMENT 4110763CD3> NIL)
  CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #<CLOS::CACHE-INFO ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START [8/2] >
  CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START 413051FA94>

Call to (CLOS::GENERIC-FUNCTION-DISCRIMINATOR (#:DISC-ARG-233520 &REST #:REST-233521)) {offset 277}

Call to ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 312}
  DBG::|rest-|            : NIL
  ENVIRONMENT:ENVIRONMENT : NIL

Handler frame: ((ERROR . #<Function 1 subfunction of ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT 4130E56DDC>))
Call to ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 326}
  SYSTEM::ARGS          : NIL
  SYSTEM::OLD  {Closed} : #<Function ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT 4130DAA40C>

Binding frame:
  MP:*INITIAL-PROCESSES* : (("The idle process" (:PRIORITY -1152921504606846976 :RESTART-ACTION :CONTINUE :INTERNAL-SERVER :IDLE) MP::PROCESS-IDLE-FUNCTION))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::I-RESTART-WITH-ENVIRONMENT-AUX {offset 202}
  ENVIRONMENT::TTY-LISTENER-P : NIL

Call to SYSTEM::RESTART-HOOK {offset 289}
  FUNCTION : SYSTEM::%TOP-LEVEL

Restart frame: (SYSTEM::TOP-LEVEL)
Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . RESTART-CASE)

Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . 2)

Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . 1)

Catch frame: SYSTEM::EXIT-LISPWORKS

Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE {offset 544}

Catch frame: SYSTEM::START-UP

Catch frame: SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION

Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 107}

Call to SYSTEM::CALL-IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 27}

Catch frame: (NIL)

Call to SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION {offset 70}
  SYSTEM::GC-MESSAGES : :DONT-KNOW

Call to SYSTEM::RESTART-NEW-STACK {offset 134}


SYSTEM::RESTART-NEW-STACK

 > Generation 7: 44141448 (0x2A18B88)
       Cons               6590208 (0x648F00)
       Non-Pointer        4434840 (0x43AB98)
       Other              10363696 (0x9E2330)
       Symbol             3811104 (0x3A2720)
       Function           18655896 (0x11CAA98)
       Non-Pointer-Static 14744 (0x3998)
       Mixed-Static       270184 (0x41F68)
       Weak               776 (0x308)
 -- Segments:
       Cons               4090038800 - 4090684000
       Non-Pointer        40A0000800 - 40A043E000
       Other              4110038800 - 4110A1D000
       Symbol             4120038800 - 41203DB000
       Function           4130038800 - 4131206000
       Non-Pointer-Static 4080000800 - 4080012000
       Mixed-Static       400004E800 - 40000AB000
       Weak               4140038800 - 4140039000
================================
 > Generation 6: 0 (0x0)
 > Generation 5: 0 (0x0)
 > Generation 4: 0 (0x0)
 > Generation 3: 0 (0x0)
 > Generation 2: 193776 (0x2F4F0)
       Non-Pointer-Static 193776 (0x2F4F0)
 -- Segments:
       Non-Pointer-Static 4040000800 - 4040032000
================================
 > Generation 1: 0 (0x0)
 > Generation 0: 2613512 (0x27E108)
       Cons               252384 (0x3D9E0)
       Non-Pointer        1275328 (0x1375C0)
       Other              780296 (0xBE808)
       Function           305312 (0x4A8A0)
       Weak               192 (0xC0)
 -- Segments:
       Cons               4010000800 - 401040B000
       Non-Pointer        4030000800 - 403040B000
       Other              4020000800 - 402040B000
       Function           4060000800 - 4060101000
       Weak               4070000800 - 4070041000
================================

Total allocated 46948736 (0x2CC6180), total size 61124608 (0x3A4B000)
```